# Calculating total underneath a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that has a quantity and calculated price right next to it. When I change the quantity inside the Gridview, the price changes right away. I want to show total price outside the gridview . I am showing the total price outside the gridview, but the price is not changing dynamically when the quantity and price changes for individual items. Below is the image of what I want. I want to $560 to be displayed and calculated right away as soon as price changes.

[image]

Below is my gridview code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdShoppingCart" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" class="ui-responsive table-stroke ss-table ui-search-result-table" GridLines="None" OnRowDataBound="grdShoppingCart_RowDataBound"  >
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="item" HeaderText="Item" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-Width="250px" ControlStyle-CssClass="ss-row"    />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-Width="300px" ControlStyle-CssClass="ss-row"    >
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblDesc" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("child") %>' /><br />
                            &nbsp;Requested By: &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblDesc1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RequestedBy") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>

                    </asp:TemplateField>
                       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"  ControlStyle-CssClass="ss-row"  >
                        <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox Width="45px" TextMode="Number" ID="txtQuantity"  Text='<%#Eval("Quantity") %>'    runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtQuantity_TextChanged" ></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="right" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" ItemStyle-Width="100px" ControlStyle-CssClass="ss-row" >
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblPrice" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                     <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" ItemStyle-Width="150px" ControlStyle-CssClass="ss-row" >
                        <ItemTemplate>
                             <asp:ImageButton CommandArgument='<%# Eval("recordId") %>' ID="imgbtnDelete" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/delete1.png"  CommandName="Delete"   ToolTip="Click To Dletee" AlternateText="Click To Dletee"/>                            
                      </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                </Columns>

            </asp:GridView>
```

his is what I tried to do in my code behind to show the total:

I declared this variable inside my class and put the value of price text box in total variable in rowDatabound

```
public string total;
protected void grdShoppingCart_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                Label lbl = (e.Row.FindControl("lblPrice") as Label);
                TextBox tbq = (e.Row.FindControl("txtQuantity") as TextBox);
                
                if(tbq.Text !="")
                {
                    lbl.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(tbq.Text) * 28).ToString();
                    total= lbl.Text.ToString(); 
                }
                    
            }
        }
```

and in the aspx page, I wrote this:

```
Total: <%=total %>
```

below is the code that changes the price and quantity:

```
 protected void txtQuantity_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox changeTextbox = sender as TextBox;
            GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)changeTextbox.NamingContainer;
            TextBox tbq = (row.FindControl("txtQuantity") as TextBox);
            Label lblPrice = (row.FindControl("lblPrice") as Label);
            lblPrice.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(tbq.Text) * 28).ToString();
     }
```

any help will be highly apprecaited.

Comment: Can you share the code which changes the price and quantity in the gridview?

Comment: you need to change your code, currently total holds only last row of price, try this method https://techaid24.com/subtotal-and-grand-total-in-gridview/

Comment: Just added the code that changes the price and quantity

Comment: @code_b, Total is not part of the gridview. Its outside the gridview.

Comment: you can only do total calculation on databind event  `grdShoppingCart_DataBind` , look at that example that gives you enough idea how to wire those events

Answer (score -4):

Your code is close. just remember that a data grid will persist in a round trip (post back), and MORE important that if  you ONLY data bind the grid on the FIRST postback = false?

Then the grid will display but the row data bind event does not re-fire (and thus no total)

So, we assume that on page back we re-bind.

Now you have this code:

```
total= lbl.Text.ToString();
```

You need

```
total = total + lbl.Text.ToString()
```

Or, of course this:

```
total += lbl.Text.ToString()
```

Or more so, you want a final total, then

```
total += lbl.Text * tbq.Text
```

but, what you have should work.

Edit:

I now see the problem is that the total price is not updating right away. But we should at least GET the final total working upon page re-fresh.

If you want the total to update as you edit? Then most easy would be in your text changed event to re-calc the total. So say code like this:

So, you can have your existing code first, and THEN add this loop in the same text changed event:

```
protected void TextBoxE_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

// total the grid
sTotal = 0;
GridViewRow gvr;

foreach (var gvr in GridView1.Rows)
{
    TextBox txtV = gvr.FindControl("lblPrice");
    if (txtV.Text != "")
        sTotal += lblprice.Text;
}
}
```

So in your text changed, you can (and need to) re-loop the rows after you updated the one row. So the above loop needs to be run. Keep in mind that the row data bound event fires for EACH row on a databind. If you on post back do a gridview databind, then you will of course loose the values in the grid. However, my bets is that you NOT doing a databind, and thus a simple loop to re-total the amount should work just fine.

The MAJOR issue here is that you left out the WHOPPER of a issue. What is that? Why of course you left out where you total things up in the first place. Since that part of yours was wrong (or at least looks to be), then my post FIRST addresed that issue and you need the +=. If your total on intitail load works, then you shoud have posted that code and how it works - since what you posted will not work.

So now that we cleared up why my post addressed the lack of total on first render.

Once you get that working (and you should have posted how that works), then and ONLY then can we address the text changed event. As above shows, it is a easy matter to re-loop and total up all rows since your changes will persist and be in that data - so right after your text changed - run/add/do the above loop to re-total.

Comment: what I have is not working. It not calculating the total right away.

Comment: Row data bind event fires for every single row - so you are assigning the single row value to total - you have to go total = total + "some value" here. That event fires row by row when the grid is rendered. How can you get a total from a single row value in row databound? You need to add the total for each row. See my edit

Comment: you can't do arithmetic operation on strings, this is wrong you need to convert to numeric before you execute any arithmetic operations. `total += lbl.Text * tbq.Text`

Comment: JSON data, XML data, values from controls on a web form? Guess what? ALL of that stuff you "touch" is text format.  With the rise of web land? Darn near ALL data you touch today is not strong typed, and is in simple text format as opposed to some binary "real" or "integer" format. Just text boxes on a web form are in fact plain text. So, in fact all day long darn near ANY code you write to work with data from the web is in fact text format. I 100% agree that some casting should be introduced - but .net does cast such data - and one is doing this all the time.  Your total example works as text.

Comment: So, AFTER the poster finally changed the = to +=? Then the other issue was the grid was inside of a update panel - but the text box was not. So, once these issues are and were addressed? Then the code will work as I posted. the OHTER huge WHOPPER the poster ignored is that in the text changed event - you HAVE to run the whole loop over each row - again the poster ignored what I suggested. Now that the poster been beaten over the head with a club - the poster now has a working solution. So the final puzzle here was that the grid was in a update panel, and the text box was not.